# Sublime Text 3 changes file permissions on save

Tags: linux, permissions, sublime-text-3

I have bunch of files with permissions `-rwxrwxr-- www-data www-data`. In order to be able to edit them, I added my user to the `www-data` group. Now when I edit and save file with Sublime Text 3, the ownership changes to my user/group. Gedit editor supplied with distro (Linux Mint 16) works fine.

How do I get Sublime Text to keep permissions intact?

Comment: There is a post with similar issues for ST2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853429/how-to-stop-sublime-text-2-from-removing-the-read-execute-flag-upon-save

Comment: @Bruno9779: thanks, but the problem/solution in that question is related to Samba

Answer (score 2):

Found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634684/what-is-sublime-text-doing-when-i-save-a-file

Adding `"atomic_save": false` to user settings file solves the problem (new files however are still created with my user group as the owner).

Comment: Glad my answer could help you out, I'll have to add your issue to the list of those caused by `atomic_save`. In regards to your other issue, it's not surprising at all that new files are created with your UID/GID, as that is the ownership that Sublime is running with. If you're into Python, it shouldn't be too difficult to write a plugin to check if you're trying to save into a particular file hierarchy, then change the user and group of the file after saving, assuming you can do that yourself from the command line without using `sudo`.

Comment: this didn't solve the problem, im using dev channel build 3095. and it adds x permissions to the file I save. I am coding in windows and the files are being accessed through samba

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue on ubuntu and used below commands to give save permission

```
sudo chmod 775 -R /var/www/folder_path 

sudo chown username -R /var/www/folder_path
```

please note: /var/www/folder_path is your project folder path or directory where you want to save file.